# VBA search column for strings and copy row to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Not really good at VBA here. Found and edited some code that I believe can help me.
I need this code to search 2 columns (L and M) for any string in those columns that ends with _LC _LR etc... Example: xxxxxxxx_LC . 
If the cell ends with anything in the array, I need the row to be copied to a new sheet. Here is what I have:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String
Dim maxKeywords As Integer


maxKeywords = 6
ReDim keywords(1 To maxKeywords)

maxKeywords(1) = "_LC"
maxKeywords(2) = "_LR"
maxKeywords(3) = "_LF"
maxKeywords(4) = "_W"
maxKeywords(5) = "_R"
maxKeywords(6) = "_RW"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For Each rngCell In Range("L2:L, M2:M" & lngLstRow)
    For i = 1 To maxKeywords
            If keywords(i) = rngCell.Value Then
                rngCell.EntireRow.Copy
                    Sheets("sheet1").Select
                        Range("L65536, M65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
                        Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    Sheets("Results").Select

            End If
        Next i
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: "here is what I have" - what does it do? Have you tested it? Did it do anything? How did the effect of this code differ from your expectations? Are there errors? What section of the code do you believe is causing these discrepencies? And, most importantly **can you read the code at all? Because if not, you shouldn't be pasting together code you find online**.

Comment: To piggyback of @Grade'Eh'Bacon (no awful pun intended :P), this won't work: `Range("L2:L, M2:M" & lngLstRow)`.  I'd take a step back, and read through it and you should be able to see how to go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I apologize for not being more informative. I keep getting this error Compile error: Expected array. It highlights the 1st declaration of array: maxKeywords(1) So no it doesn't do anything. I am also unsure about the range. I don't think I edited that correctly. I was referencing some articles and figured I'd give it a try.  I know it has an If statement, an array and a loop LOL. Just trying to speed up my work. Any help would be great.

Comment: Oh, woah. Taking a look at it, you're mixing all sorts of types.  You `Dim maxKeywords as Integer`, but then try to redim it to an array? That's not going to work. You just need to take a look, have a think, and redefine the types.  Example, you do `Dim maxKeywords as Integer`, but then use it as an array a few steps later.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the issue I think is with your variable declarations.  Before I continue, I will echo @GradeEhBacon's comment that if you can't read this and understand what's going on, you may want to take some time to learn VBA before running.

This should work, AFAIK.  You didn't specify which sheet has what info, so that may have to be tweaked. Try the below, and let me know what is/isn't working:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String, maxKeywords() As String
Dim totalKeywords As Integer, i&
Dim ws As Worksheet, resultsWS As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set resultsWS = Sheets("Results")

totalKeywords = 6
ReDim keywords(1 To totalKeywords)
ReDim maxKeywords(1 To totalKeywords)

maxKeywords(1) = "_LC"
maxKeywords(2) = "_LR"
maxKeywords(3) = "_LF"
maxKeywords(4) = "_W"
maxKeywords(5) = "_R"
maxKeywords(6) = "_RW"

 lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count  'Assuming "Sheet1" is what you want to get the last range of.

Dim k&                       ' create a Long to use as Column numbers for the loop
For k = 12 To 13             ' 12 is column L, 13 is M
    With ws                  'I'm assuming your Ranges are on the "Sheet1" worksheet
        For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(1, k), .Cells(lngLstRow, k))
            For i = LBound(maxKeywords) To UBound(maxKeywords)
                If maxKeywords(i) = Right(rngCell.Value, 3) or maxKeywords(i) = Right(rngCell.Value, 2) Then
                    ' rngCell.EntireRow.Copy
                    ' ws.Range("L65536, M65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    resultsWS.Cells(65536, k).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Value = rngCell.EntireRow.Value
                End If
            Next i
        Next rngCell
    End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce for helping. The code runs without any errors but it doesn't do anything. The "Results" sheet is left unpopulated.

Comment: Bruce, yes the range is in "Sheet1". I created a 2nd sheet labeled "Results".

Comment: Bruce, yes the range is in "Sheet1". I created a 2nd sheet labeled "Results". I have data in columns A-M, with L & M having strings as such, xxxxxx_LW. Some of these strings do not have _LW, those ones I want to leave behind. As I said before, the "Results" sheet is left unpopulated. I ran the code both in ThisWorkbook and a Module. Thank you again for your help. If we can get this working I would be happy to send you some cash via paypal. I cannot go another week sifting through rows in excel.

Comment: @vince, I'll look back over it and make some tweaks. In the meantime would it be possible to show a sample table of the "before and after"? (No worries if not, it just might make it a little more clear)

Comment: Heres a link to an image I uploaded: http://s2.postimg.org/iv3s6263d/sample.png    Bascially I want to copy all the rows to a new sheet except for the one's highlighted yellow. So basically the _LW etc.. could be in either column, L or M, it is not always in both. Thanks again for your help Bruce

Comment: Also, there is no change at all after running the code.

Comment: @Vince - I think I got it. I had some silly errors that I fixed up. This should work for you. Let me know if not!

Comment: Bruce, thank you so much! We are almost there! It did copy the the two columns to the Results page. Only a few things now need to be tweaked.

Since we're looking at two separate columns, I would like to keep the two columns separate, not all in one column as it is now after running the macro. Also I need the whole row corresponding to those special columns. Right now only L is being populated. Thank you again so much for our help! I can see the light at the end of the tunnel!

Comment: @Vince - Check my edited code, I think it's doing what you want. It copies the whole row from Sheet1, when finding a match to the end ("_LW", etc) and should put the columns info in their respective columns.

Comment: Bruce you are the MAN! It is doing exactly what I need it to do. There is still just one little problem though. It's not picking up the singular keywords such as _W and _R. Is there an easy solution for this? How can I get your paypal?

Comment: @Vince - Try the new code (I just added the `Or` statement to check for 2 characters as well as 3). And I really appreciate your offer for PayPal, but I'm just happy to help out! This was fun to work through.

Comment: Wow Bruce, thank you so much. It works perfectly and it has taken one of the worst things out of my job! You're a great person and I'm glad you enjoyed it! If you change your mind about the PayPal thing just say! Think of it as a return in kindness.

Comment: @Vince - No worries!  My suggestion from here is to look at your original code, and the code that works, side by side, and see if you can follow the logic.  The code I provided isn't too complex (except perhaps the loop logic), and you can tweak this in many ways to do other things.  Notably, see how I checked for the "_LW" or "_R" with `maxKeywords(i) = Right(rngCell.Value, 3) or maxKeywords(i) = Right(rngCell.Value, 2) `, whereas your code was looking for the enitre cell to be "_R" or whatever (`keywords(i) = rngCell.Value`).  Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for:

==================================================

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String
Dim maxKeywords, i, j, k As Integer


maxKeywords = 6
ReDim keywords(1 To maxKeywords)

keywords(1) = "_LC"
keywords(2) = "_LR"
keywords(3) = "_LF"
keywords(4) = "_W"
keywords(5) = "_R"
keywords(6) = "_RW"

lngLstRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For j = 1 To lngLstRow
  For i = 1 To maxKeywords
    If keywords(i) = Right(Sheets("Results").Range("L" & j).Value,     Len(keywords(i))) Or _
      keywords(i) = Right(Sheets("Results").Range("M" & j).Value, Len(keywords(i))) Then
        k = k + 1
          Rows(j & ":" & j).Copy
            Sheets("sheet1").Select
              Range("A" & k).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If
  Next i
Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Blue, I also tried your code. It ran but didn't do anything.