# VBA: Macro to copy cells that fall under condition to new tab

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

The code below will scan each column and copy the whole row that falls under the conditions (SEA, CUA, etc... and are red) to a sheet called "FileShares."  (It is half way complete!!)

I would like two things done now, instead of copying the whole rows,  I would like it to copy from source sheet (see example dataset1) the Target System (Application), UserID and Role Name to the destination sheet, "Fileshares" (see example dataset2) for each cells that matches the conditions. Only the bold headers will need to be filled. For the "Action" column, Remove needs to be placed into each row that has data.

Also, I would like to search columns dynamically up to the nth column (last column in the sheet) instead of hardcoding variable "k".

Any help, insight or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image: Example dataset1] [image: Example dataset2]

```
Sub BulkUpload()
Dim rngCell As Range
Dim lngLstRow As Long
Dim keywords() As String, maxKeywords() As String
Dim totalKeywords As Integer, i&
Dim ws As Worksheet, resultsWS As Worksheet



Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "FileShares"

Call Template


Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set resultsWS = Sheets("FileShares")


totalKeywords = 8
ReDim keywords(1 To totalKeywords)
ReDim maxKeywords(1 To totalKeywords)

maxKeywords(1) = "SEA"
maxKeywords(2) = "CUA"
maxKeywords(3) = "CCA"
maxKeywords(4) = "CAA"
maxKeywords(5) = "AdA"
maxKeywords(6) = "X"
maxKeywords(7) = "CUA" & Chr(10) & "SEA"
maxKeywords(8) = "CCA" & Chr(10) & "CUA" & Chr(10) & "SEA"


 lngLstRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
 Worksheets("FileShares").Select


j = 6
p = 1
q = 6

Dim k&                       ' create a Long to use as Column numbers for the loop
For k = 9 To 50
     With ws
         For Each rngCell In .Range(.Cells(8, k), .Cells(lngLstRow, k))

             For i = LBound(maxKeywords) To UBound(maxKeywords)
                If rngCell.Value = maxKeywords(i) And   rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
                resultsWS.Cells(1000, k).End(xlUp).Offset(j + p, 0).EntireRow.Value = rngCell.EntireRow.Value

            j = q + p - 7 'Used to start at row 8 and every row after
            End If
        Next i
    Next rngCell

End With
Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: So, essentially you got @BruceWayne to [write the code for you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35515223/1153513) and now you want yet another user here to code the rest for you? How about some effort on your side with an **attempt** to implement the new  functionality yourself?

Comment: Yes BruceWayne was kind of enough to help me last year and I'm very grateful for that!. I've made some changes I figured out how to change. You wouldn't believe how long it took me to get the offset to work the way I wanted. And I've tried to change copying the whole rows and instead, the specific cells myself but I have not made any ground. I am trying here! Thanks Ralph.

Answer (score 0):

Excel can help you write your macros!

Using the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB), perform the action manually.  The recorder will transform your clicks and button presses into VBA.

Once recorded, [step through](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) your code.  VBA's [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) includes a great feature.  Pressing F8 allows you to advance the code one line at a time.  This will help you figure out what each part of the recorded macro does.  **Top tip:** Split your screen, so you can see both Excel and the VBA window.  This will help get to grips with the code, as you see the impact each line has on the [UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_interface).

When you find a line of code you do not understand refer to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194068.aspx).  Most items include a working example, as well as an explanation.

You can learn so much following this technique.  But there is a limit.  If you cannot perform the action manually, you cannot record it.  To take your skills to the next level I would recommend (in order):

1. Attend a training course.
2. Read a [book](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=vba).
3. Read [blogs](http://www.mrexcel.com/).

Although the internet contains a wealth of information most of it is in bite sized chunks.  Courses and books cover the fundamentals in detail, giving you the tools you'll need to solve these problems.

I like books published by [Wrox](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/).  But I would recommend you preview a page or two before buying.  I hate reading books written in a style I do not get on with.

Comment: Thank you very much Destination-data. That step through should help me  a lot.  I have taken an intro to programming class many years ago so perhaps stepping through it will make most sense to me.